# SQLite Ionic 3 - Problema ao salvar respostas do SELECT em um array

Tags: ionic, sqlite

Eu estou em um projeto usando Ionic 3 e preciso manipular dados em sqlite. O problema atual é o seguinte, eu executo um SELECT em uma tabela e armazeno o retorno em um array (this.list_off) criado na class. Quando uso o console.log pra mostrar o valor deste array DENTRO da função de busca no banco, ele me mostra os dados que preciso, mas quando tento usar esse array fora (após o SELECT que armazena os dados nele) o array está vazio, como se numca tivesse sido preenchido. 
Há alguma forma diferente de retornar e armazenar os dados de um SELECT em sqlite?

```
 getKeyList(){
   this.sqlite.create({
    name: 'rfleet.bd',
    location: 'default'
  }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
  db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM app_teclado WHERE list_id= 1', [])
    .then(res => {
      for(var i=0; i<res.rows.length; i++) {
        this.list_off.push({tec_id:res.rows.item(i).tec_id, tec_codigo:res.rows.item(i).tec_codigo,
          tec_data:res.rows.item(i).tec_data, tec_status:res.rows.item(i).tec_status,
          inst_id:res.rows.item(i).inst_id, list_id:res.rows.item(i).list_id, tipo:res.rows.item(i).tipo})
      } 

    }).catch(e => console.log("SELECT TECLADO ERROR", e) );
}).catch(e => console.log(e));
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encotrei uma solução, só nao tenho certeza se é a melhor forma. Fiz com que a função trabalhe com respostas em "promessa", onde o retorno da função é um RESULT, tipo chamada com ajax.

```
getListId(){
return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  this.sqlite.create({
    name: 'rfleet.bd',
    location: 'default'
  }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM app_listaoff WHERE list_status = 0', [])
      .then(res => {
          let id
          if(res.rows.length > 0){
            id = res.rows.item(0).list_id;
          }
          console.log("LAST list_id inserted", id);
          resolve(id)

      }).catch(e => console.log("SELECT app_listoff ERROR", e));
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
})
```

Aqui é a chamada e o modo como recebo a resposta da função.

```
this.getListId().then(res =>{
  this.list_id = res
})
```